# dropbox clone - To use Active Storage directly on User Model or Have a separate Model handling the file attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm building an app similar to Dropbox's concept where file storage is the key feature. It struck me when I started planning the app as to whether I should:

1. Have a User Model with `has_many_attached` to handle all files/images related to a user
2. Have a UserFile Model with `has_one_attached` and `belongs_to :user`

Still a rookie here, and I guess my concern is that I'm not sure if option 1 will have more limitations as the database grow in the future and accessing, storing, viewing, updating, and deleting any files belonging to the user may not be as flexible.

Also, additional tracking on the file is required, i.e. download counter, document verified etc.

Looking at option 2, it is definitely working but it makes the flow more complex and definitely will be difficult to maintain down the road.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Have search for stackoverflow and even rails guides but there is no information that I can see that helps me on this decision. At least, perhaps i cannot understand them.

Comment: I think you should go with option 2. because if you build dropbox like application then you need to store upload file other option also

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have been playing around with active storage... its really good. just like you said.. the issue lies with other attributes that we want to store along with the file. I will go ahead with option 2 and shall share if i find any major hiccups with this approach. Thanks!

Comment: no worries man let me know if you need my help